# Is there a way to make Xerces-C pretty-print XML without double-spaced lines?

Tags: c++, xml, xerces

I'm using xerces-c to write XML.  By default it writes the entire DOM as a single line of text.  I tried the pretty-print option, like below, and now it prints double-spaced lines - which isn't very pretty, in my opinion.  Is there a way to avoid the double-spacing?

```
void configureWriter(DOMLSSerializer* writer) {
    writer->getDomConfig()->setParameter(XMLUni::fgDOMWRTFormatPrettyPrint, true);
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<MyDocument>

  <A>B</A>

  <D>E</D>

</MyDocument>
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found an answer.  There's a different option called "fgDOMWRTXercesPrettyPrint", and if you also turn this *off* then there are no empty lines in the output.

```
void configureWriter(DOMLSSerializer* writer) {
  writer->getDomConfig()->setParameter(XMLUni::fgDOMWRTFormatPrettyPrint, true);
  writer->getDomConfig()->setParameter(XMLUni::fgDOMWRTXercesPrettyPrint, false);
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<MyDocument>
  <A>B</A>
  <D>E</D>
</MyDocument>
```

This was the mail thread which gave me the answer: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox//xerces-c-users/200908.mbox/%3C4A7697C0.1000304@datadirect.com%3E